# Tool to collect stacktraces in server logs

Tags: java, log-files

Is there a tool collect and count all different stacktraces in a bunch of server logfiles?

Sometimes you have just too many stacktraces that repeat over and over. So it can be difficult to spot different problems between the stacktraces. So the idea would be to have a tool that looks for stacktraces, compares them and counts them. It would be nice if the tool could ignore minor differences (e.g. $Proxy150.dispatchCalls() versus $Proxy25.dispatchCalls() ).

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://exctractor.sourceforge.net/), takes sometime to setup, but once you get it working it works a treat. Pretty basic though, but for finding/sorting will do. Also does the "ignore" bit you mention.